# Laravel 5.2, cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: foreign-keys, laravel-5, database-migration, foreign-key-relationship

i really need help guys, i used the "make:auth" feature of laravel, now im trying to make a foreign key with the "user" table generated by the frame work . but it always throws an error - (general error: 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint). it only had an error of im trying to make table relation in the "user" table .
 i've been stuck here for a while now, heres my code, i need your help guys. thank you in advance !

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->integer('number');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('avatar')->default('default.jpg');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('role');

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('photo')->default('default.jpg');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be your typo at the foreign key declaration. Try to change it to:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: f***ccckkkk !! hahaha
thanks sir, i forgot about the naming convention of Laravel . thanks sir .

Comment: @MencioLicious you are welcome sir, I am glad to hear that I am able to help. Would you mind to mark accept my answer, thanks =)